# apply dynamically id

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to make a dynamic div using eval
the code is occur error.
The server tag is not well formed.
please help this.
My code is :

[i have attach the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqY1K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in ServiceDAO.editVersionDT.Rows)
                              {
                                  Button btn = new Button();
                                  btn.ID = "btn_" + item["answer_id"] + "";
                                  btn.Text = "Edit V" + item["version"] + "";
                                  li.Controls.Add(btn);
                              }
```

Comment: I have to create dynamic div on aspx page.
the code occur error : The server tag is not well formed.
My Code: <ul id="ulVersions<%# Eval("question_Id")%>" runat="server">
Please Help this

Comment: try this : <ul id='ulVersions<%# Eval("question_Id")%>' runat="server"> . the problem is with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `li` to some `container`. You are creating `li` control but not adding it anywhere.

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in ServiceDAO.editVersionDT.Rows)
{
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID = "btn_" + item["answer_id"] + "";
btn.Text = "Edit V" + item["version"] + "";
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.Controls.Add(btn);
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.IO.StringWriter stWriter = new      System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
li.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: li use inside ul when ul with runat server the code is not working.

Comment: Please update your question with whole code related to this,

Comment: You can put this code in code behind file and it will work fine.

Comment: I have update the answer please check now also create `HtmlGenericControl` inside `foreach` loop.